# How to check an activity of external App has "exported=false" without actually starting the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, start-activity, android-securityexception

Some custom OS by manufacturers has implemented customized features or hidden features in settings.(example: ColorOS, MIUI, FlymeOS, EMUI) I've tried to open some activities of those system APP. I used `context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null` to check if those activities exist.

Even if those activities exist, but when I `startActivity(intent);` , sometimes it causes a security exception because the manifest of that activity has declared `exported=false`, or it uses some strange permission(Example: `<uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE" />` )  Additionally, those security variables are not always same on different firmware version, so I need to check them manually. I understand I can use `try{} catch{}` to handle `startActivity();` and display an error toast when starting it failed.

**However, in my APP I would like to list many clickable buttons link to those activities. If I list many buttons and most of them result in showing an error toast when click, this is not definitely a good idea. Instead of showing all the buttons, I need to hide those button points to activities that can not be started even if they exist. If I call `startActivity()` with `try{} catch{}` to check it one by one, the user will see many activities being launched and I don't want this to happen.**

How can I check if the activity of a third-party app can be started, but without actually calling `startActivity()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`resolveActivityInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#resolveActivityInfo(android.content.pm.PackageManager,%20int)) method instead of `resolveActivity()` to get an [`ActivityInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo) object. This object extends `ComponentInfo` which has an [`exported`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ComponentInfo#exported) property you can use to see if the Activity is exported.

```
ActivityInfo info = intent.resolveActivityInfo(context.getPackageManager(),
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
boolean show = info != null && info.exported;
```